# ASP.NET MVC: EF with database first - what do to if models != db tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What should I do if I have a Model which properties have to be filled from multiple tables from the EDMX file?
Should the Controller or specific actions do this work for me? Or is EF the wrong technology in this case because I [maybe] have to execute multiple statements to built a single model object for my view?

**Update**: Why is nobody mentioning ViewModels? I think this is the way to go? http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/aspnetmvc - One of the guys told me that it´s a standard approach to build a model from multiple entities from the db. So I´ll accept that?! Can anyone please give me a last "OK" on that? I think all this stuff has confused me because my mind wasn´t clear about the term "Model". I doesn´t have to be a 1:1 relationship and what I´m actually working with are VIEWmodels... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating ViewModel classes.

Answer (score 0):

[Code First approach](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx). This way you control how the db maps to your model.

Comment: If I have an existing database, isn´t "Database First" my way to go then? Why/how should I pick Code First in this case? Though I´m able to map this myself... this would be the hardcore way, right? I´m not that familiar with EF and at the time being I feel comfortable with adding my entities within the designer.